# In New Jersey USA, if married couple buys a house, is the default "tenants in common" or "joint tenants"?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, new-jersey

In New Jersey USA, if a married couple acquires real estate, is it by default "tenants in common" or "joint tenants" (if not expressly stated on the deed)?

Answer (score -3):

it is by default whatever is listed on the granting deed:  tenants in common or joint with rights of survivorship.

Or, ...  er... quitclaim, or warranty/non-warranty...or...

i.e. whatever is on the granting deed is the "default."

Comment: The deeds do not state it, i.e. they do not say "as tenants in common" and they do not say "as joint tenants" anywhere on the deeds.

Comment: If the deed does not say "joint tenants with rights of survivorship" then it is not a joint tenancy.